# library for converting regular expressions to NFAs?

Tags: regex, state-machine, dfa, nfa

Is there a good **library** for converting **Regular Expressions** into **NFAs**?  I see lots of academic papers on the subject, which are helpful, but not much in the way of working code.

My question is due partially to curiosity, and partially to an actual need to speed up regular expression matching on a production system I'm working on.  Although it might be fun to explore this subject for learning's sake, I'm not sure it's a "practical" solution to speeding up our pattern matching.  We're a Java shop, but would happily take pointers to good code in any language.

**Edit**:

Interesting, I did not know that Java's regexps were already NFAs.  The title of [this paper](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) lead me to believe otherwise.  Incidentally, we are currently doing our regexp matching in Postgres; if the simple solution is to move the matching into the Java code that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing your need to speed up your regexes:

Java's implementation of its regex engine is NFA based.  As such, to tune your regexes, I would say that you would benefit from a deeper understanding of how the engine is implemented.

And as such I direct you to: [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/) The book gives substantial treatment to the NFA engine and how it performs matches, including how to tune your regex specific to the NFA engine.

Additionally, look into [Atomic Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for tuning your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on java+regexes.  But, if I understand correctly...

If Java's regular expression matcher is similar to most others, it does use NFA's - but not the way you might expect.  Instead of the forward-only implementation you may have heard about, it's using a backtracking solution which simplifies subexpression matching, and is probably required for Backreference usage.  However, it performs alternation poorly.

You want to see: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html (concerning edge cases which perform poorly on this altered architecture).

I've also written a question which I suppose comes down to the same thing:

[Regex implementation that can handle machine-generated regex's: *non-backtracking*, O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178173/practical-on-regex-implementation-for-use-with-machine-generated-regexs)

But basically, it looks like for some very odd reason all common major-vendor regex implementaions have terrible performance when used on certain regexes, even though this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a googler, not an expert on regexes.

There is a bunch of faster-than-JDK regex libraries one of which is *dk.brics.automaton*. According to the benchmark linked in the [article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/tomwhite/archive/2006/03/a_faster_java_r.html), it is approximately x20 faster than the JDK implementation.

This library was written by Anders Møller and had also been [mavenized](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dk.brics.automaton/automaton/1.11-8).